# Fixing a closure within a loop

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm going through **JavaScript: The Definitive Guide** by David Flanagan and I am stuck at the following example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elt = elements[i];
        var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];
        title.onclick = function() {
            if(elt.className == "reveal") elt.className = "revealed";
            else if(elt.className == "revealed") elt.className = "reveal;"
        }
    }
};

<div class="reveal">
    <h1 class="handle">Click Here to Reveal Hidden Text</h1>
    <p>This paragraph is hidden. It appears when you click on the title.</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the code in its current form works, but if I were to add more than one `div` with the class of `reveal`, no matter what `h1` element I click on, only the last one will expand. What should I change in the code for it to work on separate divs?

P.S. I do understand that this kind of question is asked quite frequently due to the nature of the problem being closures within a loop, but I'm not able to make my code work given the solutions to similar questions on SO. Thank you.

Comment: i would use event delegation and bind to the container, that way, anything added afterwards is ready to go.

Comment: A bit nicer to read, but you could use `var title = elt.querySelector(".handle");` instead of manually returning the first instance of an HTML collection.

Comment: Please show us your attempts at using closures. It is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, **variable scope** is set at the **function level**. Functions create **closures** which essentially define the boundaries of the scope. A **child scope** can access variables defined in a **parent scope**, but not the other way around.

When you invoke the `onclick` handler function, it must look **up** the **scope chain** to find the variable `elt` because  `elt` is not declared within the current scope.

The next level up in the scope chain is your `window.onload` handler function (i.e., closure). At this scope, the variable `elt` **is** declared and it's value is set by the loop. *But remember*, when you click the `<h1>` and invoke the `onclick` handler, **the loop has already terminated**. Therefore, `elt` will always be the last value set in the loop. This is why you're always getting `elt` as the last element.

To resolve this issue, you may use an **immediate executing function**. The immediate executing function creates a new closure (and scope) where `elt` is declared locally. Because the variable `elt` is now declared in this new inner scope, it is not modified by the loop in the parent scope:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elt = elements[i];
        var title = elt.getElementsByClassName("handle")[0];
        title.onclick = (function(elt) {
            return function() {
                if(elt.className == "reveal") elt.className = "revealed";
                else if(elt.className == "revealed") elt.className = "reveal;"
            };
        })(elt);
    }
};
```